# start NavigationDrawer open

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

How do I start my app with the navigation drawer open? I am not asking about setting preferences. I imagine I have to use `openDrawer`. But I don't know how. The following does not work:

```
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);   
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
```

Neither does the following

```
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Where are you putting your code? it should be on the onResume part of your activity.

Comment: Is your Navigation Drawer already working?

Comment: check the docs http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: `openDrawer()` works for me. What does "the following does not work mean?" What behavior do you observer? Does it crash, or simply not open?

Comment: My code is in onCreate just as in the android tutorial. The drawer is indeed working. But I want the drawer to be open when the user starts my app. Right now it is closed and I have to pull it.

Comment: @Tanis.7x `openDrawer` takes a parameter. The example I show you is not working for me. My example is exactly as in the sample library referred in http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#top

Comment: I'm aware it takes a parameter. For brevity's sake, I omit arguments when I only need to reference a method's name in a comment. Another user suggested moving it to onResume, have you tried that?

Comment: ha. Thank you. putting it in onResume works. @Tanis.7x my comment was meant to ask which parameter should I pass it as there are two overloaded versions of the method.